# If a short exact sequence splits we have a semidirect product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, exact-sequence, semidirect-product

There are a lot of similar questions concerning this fact, and I looked through them all but the answers tend to take larger steps and I'm having a hard time following them.

Suppose that $1\to L \rightarrow H \rightarrow R\to 1$ is a short exact sequence of groups that splits via some $\epsilon: R \rightarrow H$. I want to show that in this case $H$ is the semidirect product of $R$ and $L$.

To do this I consider the $R$-action on $H$ which is just the conjugation $h \mapsto r h r^{-1}$. (Do I understand correctly that this we can only do since we have an injective $\epsilon: R \rightarrow H$?) As $L$ is normal in $H$ it is preserved by every such conjugation and we have for each $r\in R$ a group isomorphism $l \mapsto r l r^{-1}$. In turn this means that we have defined a group homomorphism $\alpha: R \rightarrow Aut(L)$. So I see that this means that we can define the semidirect product of $L$ and $R$ along this map $\alpha$, $L \rtimes_\alpha R$.

However, now I would need to show that this semidirect product is isomorphic to $H$. To do this I would like to write out explicitly the group isomorphism. The answers I've  seen on this site didn't spell this out carefully. What is the group isomorphism that demonstrates that $H \equiv L \rtimes_\alpha R$?

Comment: Are $L$, $H$ and $R$ groups? And what's your definition of a semidirect product? Mine is there exists $K$ normal in $G$ and $H$ a subgroup of $G$ such that $K\cap H=1$ and $G=HK$.

Comment: Yes, groups, I added that. I am trying to show that H is isomorphic to the external semidirect product. To be honest, I am not 100% sure about the differences between the external/internal semidirect products. @DavidA.Craven

Comment: You are asking why the internal and external semidirect products are the same.

Comment: No, I'm asking about how to conclude the above proof that H is isomorphic to the external semidirect product of L and R.

Comment: It's absolutely clear that a split exact sequence is the same thing as an internal semidirect product. So you are asking what I claim you are asking.

Comment: That might be true, ie. that these questions are equivalent, however I'm interested in this mostly in a pedagogical way, so I guess I'm looking for a way to conclude my proof with no reference to the internal semidirect product. @DavidA.Craven

Comment: OK. Then write $h=(l,r)$, and then map $(l,r)$ to $(l,r)$. For this, let $r$ be the image of $h$ under the quotient map, and let $l$ be the element $hr^{-1}$, where we map $R$ inside $H$ via the inverse.

Comment: You may find this reference useful. It gives a rather explicit description of both inner and outer semidirect products, and also references the result you are trying to prove: the splitting lemma for groups. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product)

Comment: To add, the calculation that will show the isomorphism explicit is based on this (from same reference): Then $G$ is isomorphic to the semidirect product $N \rtimes_{\varphi} H$. The isomorphism $\lambda : G \rightarrow N \rtimes_{\varphi} H$ is well defined by $\lambda(a) = \lambda (nh) = (n, h)$ due to the uniqueness of the decomposition $a = nh$.